# React - Changing & reacting to changes in deeply nested state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I declare some state which represents a graph, modeled as an object which looks like this:

```
const [graph, setGraph] = useState({
    nodes: [{
        id: 1, name: "abc",
    },
    {
        id: 2, name: "def",
    },
    {
        id: 3, name: "ghi",
    },
],
    edges: [[1,2], [2,3]]
})
```

I want to be able to watch changes like:

- adding a new node
- modifying an existing node
- adding a new edge
- removing an edge

and be able to watch and react to those changes.

I could do something like this, for example to add a new node:

```
setGraph((graph) => ({
    ...graph,
    nodes: [
        ...graph.nodes,
        newNode
   ]
})
```

However, imagine having deeper nestedness instead of just one level - this becomes impractical fairly quickly. With updating a node, this would be even more cumbersome to do in a functional style, having to `filter` for nodes with an `id` different than the one edited and adding the edited version back into the array.

Is there a simpler way to watch the whole nested structure and react to changes to it or to any of its members (and *their* members, and so on)?

For example, let's say I want to call a function `drawGraph` that re-draws the entire graph any time it changes (this is due to other business constraints). How do I make sure to call that function each and every time a node or edge is added or updated?

Answer (score 2):

Try immer.js, with it you just specify what has changed at any level of nesting and it will automatically take care of all the changes that need to be handled. The answer ofcourse is to a more general question of how do i manually update deeply nested object properties without having to manually duplicate all the objects at each level.
https://immerjs.github.io/immer/

Comment: This is excellent advice! I'll give it a try and see if it solves my use case, but by the looks of it, it definitely should

Answer (score 0):

you can create a deep copy and store it in a new variable then use it in setState. Spread operator doesn't deep copy nested objects. you can do it in few other ways.

```
const tempGraph = JSON.stringify({...graph, nodes: [...graph.nodes, newNode]})
setGraph(JSON.parse(tempGraph))
```

you can also install lodash and deep copy using it's cloneDeep function.

now any edge or node update no matter how deeply nested it is should re-render your component. and you can put the graph state in your useEffect dependency array to run your function

```
useEffect(()=>{
somFunction();
},[graph])
```

Comment: You are talking about a problem that I might face when actually setting the new state. My issue though, is that if I simply put `graph` as a dependency, a change to a node or edge will not cause the effect to be triggered again. I need a way to watch for nested changes inside of the graph.

Comment: putting [JSON.stringify(graph)]);  as your dependency array should also do the trick, but you will always need to update the state after modifying/removing item in any way and you shouldn't directly mutate the state

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify(graph)` instead of `graph` as dependency of the array

```
useEffect(()=>{
  whatever();
},
[JSON.stringify(graph)]); // instead of [graph]);
```